# Can I move my compiled executable C code to another laptop without installation of the package?

Tags: compiling, playonlinux, source-code

I have install a package call `libcurl`, and I have compile a C code from that package into a executable. So when I run the code, I just do `.thiscode`

The problem is, I want to run `.thiscode` in another laptop, but that laptop isn't Linux and it doesn't have `libcurl` installed.

Can I just transfer `thiscode` via USB to another laptop, and will that laptop be able to run the code?

Do you think this will work?

Answer (score 1):

Not likely. When you compile c/c++ code on a linux machine it (typically) forms an ELF binary, which windows (and mac) cannot use. You can, however, use mingw-w64 to crosscompile from a linux host to a windows binary, and you can do similar things for cross compiling to mac (but the process is by and far more complicated).

Then comes the fact you mention libcurl. Perhaps you just compiled the source of that, or you wrote your own program that depends on libcurl. In the former case, the presence of libcurl on the target machine does not matter, in the latter, depending on whether you static or dynamicly link libcurl into the program, you may need the appropreate library (dll or dynlib) on the target machine.

Regardless, across widely differing operating systems one cannot simply copy/paste a binary from one to the other and expect it to work. You have to give a fair amount of forethought into the process.